# Can I recover Gmail account after I forget answers to my security questions?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have two Gmail accounts that I remember my password but forget answers to the security questions. I have used it for a while in my old devices.

However, when I tried to log in to the accounts on my new device (MacBook), I was denied to the login even though I remember the password, and was forced to answer the security questions I set.

But I forget the answers. I tried to recover the accounts from [Gmail recovery link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7682439?hl=en), but after I finished all the process (type the account address and password, and type the creation date and type another email account to verify the code and input it), it only told me that Google cannot verify it is my account.

Is it still possible to recover the accounts? I cannot access the old devices any more.

Answer (score 0):

All of the steps offered by Google to recover a Google Account can be found in the [Recover your Google Account or Gmail](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7682439?hl=en) help article that you already linked to. 
Try every option they offer, following each step carefully.

If none of these steps work for you, then the only alternative Google offers at this time is creating a new account.

This answer is assuming you're using a consumer @gmail.com account. If you're using a paid enterprise G Suite account, contact your organization's admins as they can help you regain access to your account.